# I have try to do the following code but i get those erros

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined index: voornaam in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC Registratie
>   Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined index: achternaam in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC Registratie
>   Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Undefined index: geboortedatum in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC
>   Registratie Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Undefined index: woonplaats in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC Registratie
>   Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 24
>
> Notice: Undefined index: adres in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC Registratie
>   Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 25
>
> Notice: Undefined index: nationaliteit in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC
>   Registratie Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 26
>
> Notice: Undefined index: vooropleiding in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC
>   Registratie Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 27
>
> Notice: Undefined index: niveau in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC Registratie
>   Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: methode in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC Registratie
>   Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 29
>
> Notice: Undefined index: sector in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC Registratie
>   Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined index: opleiding in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC Registratie
>   Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 31
>
> Notice: Undefined index: starten_in in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROC Registratie
>   Pagina\core\classes\Database.php on line 32

This is my code:

```
class Database{

    public $db;
    public $voornaam;
    public $achternaam;
    public $geboortedatum;
    public $woonplaats;
    public $adres;
    public $nationaliteit;
    public $vooropleiding;
    public $niveau;
    public $methode;
    public $sector;
    public $opleiding;
    public $starten_in;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db                       = new mysqli('localhost','root','','roc');
        $this->voornaam                 = $_POST['voornaam'];
        $this->achternaam               = $_POST['achternaam'];
        $this->geboortedatum            = $_POST['geboortedatum'];
        $this->woonplaats               = $_POST['woonplaats'];
        $this->adres                    = $_POST['adres'];
        $this->nationaliteit            = $_POST['nationaliteit'];
        $this->vooropleiding            = $_POST['vooropleiding'];
        $this->niveau                   = $_POST['niveau'];
        $this->methode                  = $_POST['methode'];
        $this->sector                   = $_POST['sector'];
        $this->opleiding                = $_POST['opleiding'];
        $this->starten_in               = $_POST['starten_in'];  }
```

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: its a notice not an error, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624474/php-difference-between-notice-and-warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$this->voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
```

To

```
$this->voornaam = isset($_POST['voornaam']) ? $_POST['voornaam'] : '';
```

Same with others

Answer (score 0):

The paremeters aren't in the `POST` request and you have the notice when trying to use the parameter name as index in the `$_POST` array.

You can do it if the paremeter is optional:

```
$this->voornaam = @$_POST['voornaam'];
```

so those notices aren't logged.

Comment: if there is a notice, that means something is wrong with @ you only say that even there is something wrong, don't get shown. thats wrong you need to fix it iin stead of ignore it else you could better nopt turning on notices

Comment: You can use it if the paremeters are optional. It has the same consecuences as using `isset` but setting the variable as `null`.

Comment: @francedaval yes becouse he asks why he get the notices than sayout just ignore it is no answar

Comment: I started saying that it was because the parameters aren't in the POST. And next giving an option.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$this->voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
```

To

```
$this->voornaam = !empty($_POST['voornaam']) ? $_POST['voornaam'] : '';
```

and it'll work with no notices