# Error when empty MySQL field even with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

When I click on a project in my web app, that it contains values, I do not get any error, but I created another project with empty fields in MySQL, and I clicked on it, in my web app (PHP app), so I got this error:

> Undefined variable: total in
>   C:\wamp\www\architect\projDetails.php on line 80

I have this PHP code:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(total_pay) FROM workers) total,workers. * FROM workers WHERE projects_id = ".$id." ORDER BY date_of_pay DESC";
$stmt = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysqli_error($con));
```

And here html and php code near line 80:

```
 <tr>

      <?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){ $total = 0; ?>
    <tr>
    <?php if($rows['total']!=0){
        $total = $rows['total'];
    }
    else {
        $total = "غير متوفر";
    }
        ?>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['total_pay']?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['date_of_pay']?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $name['project_name'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><!--<input class="imgClass_insert" type="submit" name="submit1" value="" />-->
        <input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" name="delete_workers" value=""/>


    </td>
  </tr>

    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  <tr>    

    <td colspan="3">مجموع تكاليف العمال في مشروع <?php echo $name['project_name']?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $total ?></td>
  </tr>
```

So when total is empty, I get the error,and when it is not empty, I don't get any errors, so what is the problem here?

Comment: I believe you need to learn the differnce between a **notice** and an **error**, you can find all you need [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624474/php-difference-between-notice-and-warning)

Comment: At the bottom of the second code block you posted you do a `echo $total`. However if the sql query at the top does _not_ return _any_ values, then `$total` is _never_ defined, thus undefined. A simple solution would be to set a safe default for `$total` _before_ the `while()` loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$total` is currently only alive within the while block. You are exiting this block at the statement `</tr><?php } ?><tr>`. That means your variable is no longer allocated in code row `<td align="center"><?php echo $total ?></td>` below. To use this total variable below the while block, add the declaration and initialization of the variable above the while block, e.g:

```
<tr>
    <?php $total = 0;
          while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <?php if($rows['total']!=0){      <-- Check this comparison (described below)
            $total = $rows['total'];
        }
        else {
            $total = "غير متوفر";
        }
        ?>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['total_pay']?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['date_of_pay']?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $name['project_name'] ?></td>
        <td align="center"><!--<input class="imgClass_insert" type="submit" name="submit1" value="" />-->
            <input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" name="delete_workers" value=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>    
    <td colspan="3">مجموع تكاليف العمال في مشروع <?php echo $name['project_name']?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $total ?></td>
</tr>
```

Hope this will work for you. The annotated line in code above will compare a string with an integer value. Please be aware that `$rows['total']` will contain a value of type String. Your comparison is against an integer value of `0`. PHP should not throw an error or warning but it could come to unwanted results in this if statement. (Further information: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php )

Comment: It is. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.

```
echo isset($total)? $total: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here if we are getting any data from DB, then only it will enter into the while loop. Now inside while loop only $total is defining.
If we define it outside the while loop, the default value, will solve the issue

```
<tr> <?php 
    $total = "0";
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){ $total = 0; 
      if($rows['total']!=0){
          $total = $rows['total'];
      }
      //.....
      //.....
    } ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">some text <?php echo $name['project_name']?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $total ?></td>
</tr>
```

Thank you