# Undefined offset 1 PHPExcel

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an undefined offset after calling my data in my table. Somehow, I can get the first record. However, for the other records, I'm having an error notice that I'm having an undefined offset.

**Data**

Detail1||Response1||Status1::Detail2||Response2||Status2::Detail3||Response3||Status3::Detail4||Response4||Status4::Detail5||Response5||Status5::Detail6||Response6||Status6::Detail7||Response7||Status7::Detail8||Response8||Status8::Detail9||Response9||Status9::Detail10||Response10||Status10::

**Result when running code**:

Detail1
Response1
Detail2
Response2
Detail3
Response3
Detail4
Response4
Detail5
Response5
Detail6
Response6
Detail7
Response7
Detail8
Response8
Detail9
Response9
Detail10
Response10

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploadexcel\export.php on line 52

**Code**:

```
$querydata = "SELECT DESCRIPTION from sample";
$resultdata = $conn->prepare($querydata);
$resultdata->execute();

$storeresult = $resultdata->fetchObject();
$resultquery = $storeresult->DESCRIPTION;


$pieces = explode("::",$resultquery);

$countVal = count($pieces);

$counter = 0;



while($counter<$countVal){
$pieces1 = explode("||", $pieces[$counter]);
$pieces2 = explode("||", $pieces[$counter]);


echo $pieces1[0]."<br>"; // detail
echo $pieces2[1]."<br>"; // response

$counter++;
$rowCount++;

}
```

Can you help me with this? I'm confused on why my code is showing that error even though it executed right.

Comment: the problem is the very last `::` in your data string. The last item of $pieces will be an empty string -> $pieces1 will be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploadexcel\export.php on line 52` its a php **notice**, not an **error** and therefore your script will **still execute**.
See [PHP difference between notice and warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624474/php-difference-between-notice-and-warning) for the difference.

Your last status (`Status10::`) is missing its `Detail` and `Response`. Therefore `echo $pieces2[1]."<br>"; // response` does throw that notice as the array key `1` does not exist there in the last iteration.

You can prevent the notice checking the arraykey before accessing:

```
if(isset($pieces2[1])) {
  echo $pieces2[1]."<br>"; // response
}
```

You should do the same thing for `$pieces2[0]`.

**Always** check array keys before accessing them.

Comment: Oh now I see. So it's only a notice, I thought it was an error. This was very informative :)

Comment: @FabianSchöner The last Status10 referres to Detail10 and Response10. The last $pieces1[0] will also be empty (still set to NULL, therefor no error).

Comment: @Jeff youre exactly right. Still the notice will be thrown as he does access it anywas, or am i mistaking? its actually a bit hard to tell while guessing what line 52 is.

Comment: Yes, the notice will be thrown anyways. But there will be no notice thrown for `$pieces1[0]` although it's content is useless (NULL). You are covering the symtom, not solving the problem imho.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the very last :: in your data string. The last item of `$pieces` will be an empty string -> $pieces1 will be null, since there's nothing to explode.

So just add a test in the loop if `$pieces[$counter]` is more than just '':

```
<?php
$resultquery = <<<EOT
Detail1||Response1||Status1::Detail2||Response2||Status2::Detail3||Response3||Status3::Detail4||Response4||St::Detail5||Response5||Status5::Detail6||Response6||Status6::Detail7||Response7||Status7::Detail8||Response8||Status8::Detail9||Response9||Status9::Detail10||Response10||Status10::
EOT;


$pieces = explode("::",$resultquery);
$countVal = count($pieces);

$counter = 0;
$rowCount = 0;

while($counter<$countVal){
    if($pieces[$counter]>'') {
       $pieces1 = explode("||", $pieces[$counter]);
       // $pieces2 = explode("||", $pieces[$counter]); // we don't need that. $pieces1 is the same as $pieces2

       echo $pieces1[0]."<br>"; // detail
       echo $pieces1[1]."<br>"; // response
    }
    $counter++;
    $rowCount++;
}
```

working snippet: https://3v4l.org/sXnNn

Answer (score -1):

use foreach loops instead of accessing the arrays directly to avoid this kind of error. Your problem occurs, because your last array has a status, but not a  response.

```
$pieces1 = explode("||", $pieces[$counter]);
foreach($pieces1 as $piece)
   printf("%s <br />", $piece);
```