# Wordpress body_class issues, call some warnings

Tags: php, wordpress, class, warnings

After i turned on my wordpress debug mode, i noticed there is some problems:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '' not found or invalid function name in /home/kafijass/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 294

Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/kafijass/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 838

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/kafijass/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 595
class="">
```

I opened, in browser, page source and found out, that warnings come from body_class. I removed body_class function from my html body tag and warnings disappeared. Why there is such mess in wordpress? And don't even start to speak woocomerce idiotic structure and errors after each update...

Answer (score 1):

There are three errors here. As I there is no stack trace its, difficult to exactly pinpoint the source of the issue but there are a lot of things that there individual warnings tell us.

1. `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '' not found or invalid function name in /home/kafijass/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 294`

This usually happens when you are using any hook, filter or action and you pass a function to it, but it is not defined. For example.

```php
add_action('wp_loaded', 'a_function_which_should_handle_it');
function not_the_correct_function() {
...
}
```

As you can see the function name doesn't match `a_function_which_should_handle_it` or it may not even entierly exist. That's the case when this type of error occurs.

2.`Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/kafijass/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 838`

This would usually occur when you are using a wordpress function on post template and it accepts array, but you haven't provided the array or maybe some edge case has occured where the type of the value is not as the function expected.This would need to be looked by a developer to fix.

3. `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/kafijass/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 595 class="">`

> The implode function in PHP is used to "join elements of an array with a string". The implode() function returns a string from elements of an array.

This again means that the function was expecting an array and you haven't pass it an array.

A good way to make sure about it is to always check for it.

```php
if (is_array($variable)) {
 // Then do something.
}
```

I hope these clues help you find the source of the error.

Comment: Thank you. Error 1 has appeared suddenly, I didn't adding, removing or editing the code

Comment: Have recently switched on the debug mode ?

Comment: Page was working fine. Client send me a screenshot, that the page not working (standard text, that wordpress has serious problem....) after switched debug mode there was some issue with wc-cart-functions (after update). I downloaded newest woocommerce and replace that file and page start working, but with thous warnings

Comment: Yes, that explains a lot. So according to my understanding you were having the issues from the start, as these are `Warning` s and not `Error`s. See the diff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30364612/8298248). Now if you turn of the debug mode you will see these warnings gone, but once you switch it on, they will come back. To fix this start by deactivating the pluign and checking this way you will be able to pinpoint the plugin responsible for it, and can then attempt to fix it via support or stackoverflow help. @aidron